# Relations exercise Charles C. Pinter

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

let $ f: A \to B  $  a surjective function. Suppose that $R$ is a relation of equivalence in $A$ such that  $ R_f \subset R $ and that $S$ is a relation of equivalence in $B$

Definition:

$\overrightarrow {f} (R)= \{ (f(x), f(y) ): (x,y) \in R \}$

Prove:

a)$ \overrightarrow {f} (R) $ is a equivalence of relation in $B$

$$\begin{array}{crl} 
\text{let  }  x \in \overrightarrow {f} (R)  &\Rightarrow & (x,x) \in R\\
&\Rightarrow & (x,x) \in R_f\\
&\Rightarrow&\ f(x)=f(y)=b\\
&\Rightarrow&\ (x,x) \in B \times B\\
&
\end{array}$$

Can you help me check this proof?

Comment: What dies $R_f$ mean?

Comment: This is the definition $ R_f =  \{ (x,y) \in A \times A  : f(x)=f(y) \} $ @Taladris

Comment: This is the definition $ R_f =  \{ (x,y) \in A \times A  : f(x)=f(y) \} $ @user951252

Comment: I see. I am not sure the notation is standard, but I learned that in France where notations slightly vary. The problem in your proof is that equivalence relation has three axioms (symmetry, reflexivity, and transitivity) and it does not seem that you checked them.

Comment: This notation is old and it is used in the book by Charles C. Pinter

Answer (score 0):

This proof makes little sense to me. In your third line you say $f(x) = f(y) = b.$ What is $y$? What is $b$?